# How to avoid line fade Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In Adobe Photoshop I like like to draw straight lines by clicking on one end point with the brush tool and then shift clicking on the other end. This gives me a nice straight line, but it fades out towards the first end point. Attached is an example.

[image]

Is there a way to avoid this fade?

Comment: Clearly, there is something in your settings for the stroke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your brush settings (F5), 'Shape Dynamics' & 'Transfer' have a Control option. The fade you see is set in one of those sections. Changing control's fade to none will remove the fade.

Comment: Now it works exactly as I want it to. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to have helped